# SVD in scipy and numpy for tensors

Tags: tensors, svd, python, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

Can someone explain to me the difference between SVD of numpy and scipy for Multidimensional arrays (Tensors)?

```
X = np.random.randn(3,3,3)
S1 = numpy.linalg.svd(X)
S2 = scipy.linalg.svd(X)
```

The **S1** here is a tuple containing **U** 3x3x3, Sigma 3x3 and **Vh** 3x3x3. But the **S2** line throws an error saying 'expected Matrix'. Thus, I use the reshape option to unfold the tensor and compute the svd using scipy.linalg as follows:

```
Xreshape = np.reshape(X, (9,3))
S2 = scipy.linalg.svd(X)
```

Now, **S2** here is a tuple containing **U** 9x9, Sigma 3x1 and **Vh** 3x3.
The elements of S1 and S2 are not the same. Could someone explain to me the theory behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to explain what's going on for the scipy svd method: the scipy method does not permit arrays of dimension 3 or higher as an input. If you feed in a matrix, it yields the SVD of that matrix.

The real question, then, is what does the numpy svd method do with the input? The answer is explained [in the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), but the explanation is a bit terse. In general (for $k \geq 3$), numpy interprets a shape $n_1 \times n_2 \times \cdots \times n_k$ array as an $n_1 \times \cdots \times n_{k-2}$ array of $n_{k-1} \times n_k$ matrices and it computes the svd of each of these matrices separately.

For your particular case, numpy interprets $X$ as a list of $3$ matrices. Let $X_i$ denote the slice `X[i,:,:]`. If `U,s,Vh` denote the components the output of `numpy.linalg.svd(X)`, then these contain and svd for each matrix $X_0$, $X_1$, and $X_2$. In particular, the matrix product

```
U[i,:,:] @ numpy.diag(s[i,:]) @ Vh[i,:,:]
```

Should be (close to being) equal to $X_i$ for $i = 0,1,2$. You should be able to verify this with

```
numpy.allclose(X[i,:,:],U[i,:,:] @ numpy.diag(s[i,:]) @ Vh[i,:,:])
```

which should return `True`. As the documentation notes, the product `U[i,:,:] @ numpy.diag(s[i,:])` can be more efficiently computed as `U[i,:,:] * s[i,None,:]`, but this is fairly confusing unless you're comfortable with numpy's broadcasting rules for array multiplication.

Comment: Hi, in general how would we reconstruct M for any dimensions (like here it is 3x3x3 which makes it much easier ig)

Comment: @Agile_Eagle I think it's easy to understand but unwieldy to explain. Let's say that the array has dimensions $n_0×n_1×⋯×n_{k−1}$ (so that I can use zero-indexing) and you have indices $0≤i[j]≤n_j-1$ for $j=0,…,k−3$. Then `U[i[0],...,i[k-3],:,:]@np.diag(s[i[0],...,i[k-3],:])@Vh[i[0],...,i[k-3],:,:]` is a reconstruction of `X[i[0],...,i[k-3],:,:]`.